# php - Seo language redirect in index

Tags: php, redirect, seo

i'm about to publish a multilanguage site, with every language under a specific dir. (ex. en/ , fr/ , it/ , ru/ )....

the site doesn't have an "index" but it should be automatically redirected to "en/index.php"

I know it can be done in hundreds of methods, but is there a good seo-friendly mode of doing this redirect ?

for now i'm using something easy as:

```
<?
header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
header( "Location: en/index.php" );
?>
```

is it the right choice (seo-friendly talking) ?

Thanksss !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably good enough. You could even use mod_rewrite to redirect the visitors without them having to load the index.php (saves on HTTP requests):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) /en/index.php [R=301,L]
```